# Sorting an array of object with another array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

So i have two array and i want to sort the array with, Also i dont want to delete unqiue keys, the solution provided deletes the key and give array of lenght 3.:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: '111',
    user: '178'
  },
  {
    id: '222',
    user: '180'
  },
  {
    id: '333',
    user: '186'
  },
  {
    id: '112',
    user: '180'
  }
]
```

```
const someUser = ['180', '186', '178']
```

And i want output as:

```
[
  {
    id: '222',
    user: '180'
  },
  {
    id: '112',
    user: '180'
  },
  {
    id: '333',
    user: '186'
  },
  {
    id: '111',
    user: '178'
  }
]
```

If we run a map or forEach loop, i want to get array of object according to the `user` field. Like if `user 180` has 2 fields in data then i want first array with 2 objects of user containing 180.

Comment: "*the solution provided deletes the key and give array of lenght 3*" Which one? There are multiple solutions in the linked question.

Comment: tried 4-5 of them, they removed similar keys and give results in array of length 3, what i want is array of length 4.

Comment: @rED, Here is your exact solution https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/VwpeNNZ

Comment: ...[I don't believe that](https://jsbin.com/ruzokak/1/edit?js,console)? That's the second solution.